# Exception when StreamInsight 2.3 is running

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, streaminsight

I have StreamInsight client:

```
var quoteStreamable = application.GetStreamable<IntradayQuote>(symbol);

var matchQuery = from quote in quoteStreamable.ToObservable()
where quote.Symbol == symbol
select new MatchPairs
{
    Quote = quote,
    Order = order
};

var sink =
application.GetObserver<MatchPairs>(StreamInsightConfiguration.Default.StreamInsightServerSinkName);
var clientProcessName = WindowsServiceUtility.InitClientProcessName(order.Id, symbol);

if (!application.Entities.ContainsKey(clientProcessName))
{

using (matchQuery.Bind(sink).Run(clientProcessName))
{
    .....
}
}
```

I have 100 clients. When I run 100 clients, the StreamInsight will be crashed.
Here is exception in event viewer:

```
Source: Application Error:

Faulting application name: StreamInsightService.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time     stamp: 0x57b1459b
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0x80131623
Fault offset: 0x12f99e0f
Faulting process id: 0x27dc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1f6aec2a424b6
Faulting application path: C:\WorkSpace\bin\Debug\StreamInsightService.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: ec7c65ff-62a3-11e6-80be-408d5c3df51a
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:* 

Source: .NET Runtime:

Application: StreamInsightService.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The application requested process termination through System.Environment.FailFast(string message).
Message: Only started or running tasks can be suspended.
Parameter name: task
Stack:
at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String)
at Microsoft.ComplexEventProcessing.Engine.InstanceManager.FilterException(System.Exception)
at Microsoft.ComplexEventProcessing.Engine.InstanceManager.ProcessCommand(Microsoft.ComplexEventProcessing.Engine.SystemCommand, Int64)
at Microsoft.ComplexEventProcessing.Engine.InstanceManagerInputStrategy.DispatchEvents(Microsoft.ComplexEventProcessing.Engine.SchedulingPolicy)
at Microsoft.ComplexEventProcessing.Engine.SchedulingPolicy.DispatchEvents()
at Microsoft.ComplexEventProcessing.Engine.DataflowTask.OnRun()
at Microsoft.ComplexEventProcessing.StreamOS.Task.Run()
at Microsoft.ComplexEventProcessing.StreamOS.Scheduler.Main()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

How to fix this problem ? or let me know what is the reason about above exception ?